# Is it possible to put a navbar on a carousel?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm not sure if it's possible to do that with Bootstrap? Something like that :[website template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vZQK.png) I was thinking maybe a z-index.

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can; in fact, you don't even need a framework to do it. Position the navbar as `fixed` or `absolute`. (Fixed will position the navbar relative to the **viewport**, and absolute will position it relative to its **container**. [Read more.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)) Then, give the navbar a z-index greater than any other element.

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1
}
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/f6yhes0w/1/